# Remove find column in mui DataGridPro's column selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a side project and currently developing a data table.

I'm using the DataGridPro from material ui at the moment and I really enjoy the column selector.

But I want to remove the section for "find column". Do anyone know if that is possible? Currently I'm using a custom toolbar with some logic in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "find column" is defined in the default element `GridColumnsPanel`. You can override it by providing the `ColumnsPanel`. You can find more information about overriding components in [this documentation page](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/).

All the components that can be overridden are [listed here](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/#slots)

If you want to get inspiration from the default component, the code is available on this [github page](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/3a78544a1249383ebcaa8eb401358682812a007a/packages/grid/_moduls_/grid/components/panel/GridColumnsPanel.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can override it with some ThemeProvider which wrap that Component.